# Informatica Lookup cache row count is more than 5 million,no issue with lkp cache but wf run Is too slow at load Session?

Tags: lookup, informatica

I have changed Truncate table to Insert and Update logic with one lookup, the look up cache row count is more than 5 million.After change to Incremental load with lookup throughout put  is now reduced to 2 from 2400 (Trunc Load)

Answer (score 0):

The data in your lookup is quite large. see if you can restrict the number of records in look up. 
If not, Assuming your source and target database are heterogeneous, instead of lookup use it as a source and then join it in as a detail table using a joiner. this should speed up the performance to a good extend.

Answer (score 0):

The session is slow to start because it is building the huge cache for your lookup to start loading the data. Ensure that you are just pulling up the columns in lookup which are required for the comparison and whatever is required as output, like the PK column etc. Use a lookup override query to tune the performance, here you can filter the data as well to pull only what is required, be it the columns or the rows. If your lookup data does not change, try using persistent cache.

Try to eliminate the lookup itself if you have the option of joining the data in the sql override itself. That way you will push the query to the db instead of informatica doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check below points to improve performance-

- Lookup tuning - reduce number of rows in lookup by joining it lookup table with source table(if they are in same DB), or apply some filter condition. makes sure you are using PK/FK/Indexed columns while joining. Also remove all unwanted columns from lookup.
- Target Tuning - Make sure while writing into target, you drop all indices from target and create indices after target load finishes off. Then make sure the key columns mentioned in Informatica target is actually inexed in DB level.
- Source Tuning - Since you havent change much here so i am not expecting many opportunity to improve here. But please check if your SQL using some index etc.